# JQuery page transitioning in IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I'm new to JQuery so don't really know too much about the JQuery I have written and how to troubleshoot it. I have had an issue with my website when running on Internet Explorer. I've created some transitions for my web pages so that the site smoothly moves from one page to the other and this is working with no problems on Chrome and Firefox. However, as soon as I go into IE9 I hit a problem! The header at the top (div name `#footer`) is the only thing transitioning! And the rest of the page fails to show up! What am I missing from my code? The code can be found live here.

As a side note... Does anybody know anywhere to get some JQuery tips or tutorials? It would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: it would help if you post your code instead of linking to your website.  post the bits of css/html/javascript causing the issue.

Comment: The problem is that I don't know WHAT is causing the issue?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking a quick poke around your site, I was able to fix the problem of content not showing up by adding 100% width and height to the body tag.  My GoogleFu skills failed me as to *why* this works, but I'd guess that it has something to do with how IE9 calculates what should and shouldn't be shown when the body element is absolutely positioned.  I imagine that if you add this to your CSS declaration on the body tag, your animations would work as expected.